# Use a variable for all Async methods in ASP.NET WebApplication

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor, web-applications

I'm rather new to ASP.NET. I have the following code defining stuff in a Model class:

```
public class DisplayTestModel : PageModel
{
    public readonly proj.Data.ApplicationDbContext _context;
    private UserManager<Data.ApplicationUser> _userManager;
    public DisplayTestModel(proj.Data.ApplicationDbContext context,
       UserManager<Data.ApplicationUser> user)
    {
        _userManager = user;
        _context = context;
    }

    public List<Models.Test> Questions;
    ...
}
```

Then I have two methods `OnPostAsync` and `OnGetAsync`.
The list `Questions` is filled with data inside `OnGetAsync`.
After submitting the form, I still want to use `Questions` inside `OnPostAsync` with the same data.

```
public async Task OnGetAsync(int id)
{
    var questions = [...]
    Questions = await questions.ToListAsync();
}

public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < Questions.Count; i++)
    {[...]}
}
```

Instead, `Questions` appears empty when executing `OnPostAsync`. Is there a way to define it that will make it retain the data after submitting the form?

Comment: ViewBag or Session?

Comment: @D-Shih Sorry. I guess it's session.

Comment: But I'm only using an Account Controller.